# Webpack 2. How to use with extract extract-text-webpack-plugin and scss?

Tags: css, sass, webpack

I'm new to `webpack` and some points of this great tool still not clear for me. Let's say that all assets bundled to app.js, but what if I want separate `css` file that webpack has bundled for me on the fly from scss? Should I reference scss library or it's enough to have node-sass? Should I reference to filnal file style.css manually?
Here my current config (that is working fine except sass).

```
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var config = require('../config')
var vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

function resolve(dir) {
    return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/main.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: config.build.assetsRoot,
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
            config.build.assetsPublicPath : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
        modules: [
            resolve('src'),
            resolve('node_modules')
        ],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
            'src': resolve('src'),
            'assets': resolve('src/assets'),
            'components': resolve('src/components')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
                enforce: "pre",
                include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
                options: {
                    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: vueLoaderConfig
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                query: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
                    loader: "css-loader!sass-loader",
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                query: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'style.css'
        })
    ]
}
```

Comment: You need to import your `scss` file in src/main.js file. This way Webpack knows it's used and it has to be processed.

Comment: @bognix, but in this case css will not downloaded parallel as in case if it is separate file, right?

Comment: you should import scss file in src/main.js and you can then load css in html using regular <link> tag. It will be loaded next to the js bundle.